# how to remove blank row (tr) from html table using javascript

Tags: javascript

i'm new on javascript and i'm using sortable.js. i have two html tables. table1 has there some data and table2 is empty. i want to remove empty row (.blank_row) when i drag & drop a row from table1 to table2. the sortable.js is working fine but my code `if conditions` not working. i want to remove blank_row from table2. if table2 is empty then i want to auto add a blank_row?

i'm using sortable.js for drag and drop list. i want to remove blank_row when i drag and drop a row?
[image]
html

```
<table class="table" >
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Story</th>
            <th>Created</th>
            <th>Timestamp</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="drag">
        <tr draggable="true" style="">
            <td> 61</td>
            <td> how can i merge two forms fields in Django?
            </td>
            <td> c0d3</td>
            <td> a day ago</td>
        </tr>
        <tr draggable="true" style="">
            <td> 59</td>
            <td>how to use custom fonts in django-ckeditor?
            </td>
            <td> c0d3</td>
            <td> 23 days ago</td>
        </tr>
        <tr draggable="true" style="">
            <td> 51</td>
            <td> how can i merge two forms fields in Django?
            </td>
            <td> c0d3</td>
            <td> 24 days ago</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Story</th>
            <th>Created</th>
            <th>Timestamp</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="drop">
        <tr class="blank_row">
            <td colspan=4 style="border: 1px dotted #000 !important;">
                &nbsp;
                Drop Here...
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

js

```
let droppable = document.querySelector('#drop').rows.length
let emptyRow = document.querySelector(".blank_row")

if (droppable > 1) {
    emptyRow.remove()
}

new Sortable(drag, {
    group: 'shared',
    animation: 150
  });

new Sortable(drop, {
    group: 'shared',
    animation: 150,
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try one of the following methods

```
if (droppable >= 1) {
  emptyRow.remove()
}
```

or

```
if (droppable > 0) {
  emptyRow.remove()
}
```

else

```
if (droppable) {
  emptyRow.remove()
}
```

The reason this code is not working is because your logic `if > 1` does not yield accurate results while your `tr` is only 1

Comment: how can i use loop for it?  how to manage empty table i want to automatically create blank_row if table is empty and remove blank_row if table is not empty?

Comment: `[...document.querySelectorAll(".blank_row")].forEach(emptyRow => {
  emptyRow.remove();
});`

Comment: or you can use `.map()` like this `document.querySelectorAll(".blank_row").map(emptyRow => { emptyRow.remove() }`

Answer (score 0):

i believe you want to remove the tr and not the body

```js
// query for all elements that have "blank_row" class
// make them as a list using spread (3 dots)
// for each of the row, remove it
[...document.querySelectorAll(".blank_row")].forEach(emptyRow => {
  emptyRow.remove();
});
```

```html
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Story</th>
      <th>Created</th>
      <th>Timestamp</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="drop">
    <tr class="blank_row">
      <td colspan=4 style="border: 1px dotted #000 !important;">
        &nbsp;
        Drop Here...
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: dear i don't understand how to define it in condition would you like to explain it.....

Comment: added some document in my answer